# React js, Cannot read property "0". When calling an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I cannot able to access the data from the fetch function. I want to pass the data from action to reducer. API is called using an fetch function, api is returned in the form of promise. So, API is called separately and data is returned back to the action payload.

```js
import { INDEX_PRESCRIPTION } from '../constant.js';

function fetch_prescription(){
  const base_url= "http://192.168.1.22:3000/api/v1/";
  const fetch_url = `${base_url}/prescriptions`;
  let datas = [];
  return fetch(fetch_url, {
    method: "GET"
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    datas.push(data['prescriptions'])
    return datas
  })
}

export const indexPrescription = async () => {
  const action = {
    type: INDEX_PRESCRIPTION,
    details: await fetch_prescription()
  }
  return action;
  console.log('action details', action.details)
}

export const getIndexPrescription = (dispatch) => {
   dispatch(indexPrescription());
}
```

On examining the console, we get:

[image]

How to access the prescription details. I tried to access it by `action.details["0"]["0"]` , but results in 'Cannot read property "0" of undefined '. I have gone through many questions and solution related to this problem, but cant able to study what is going wrong with my code.

**Update** Here is my index.jsx component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { getIndexPrescription } from '../actions/index.js';

class Index extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      prescription: null
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.getIndexPrescription();
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <h2>
        Prescription Index
      </h2>
    )
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({ getIndexPrescription }, dispatch)
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    prescription: state
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Index);
```

And My src/index.js file is

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import reducer from './reducers';
import Index from './components/index.jsx';

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
    <Index />
 </Provider>, document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your promise is resolved only after you have answer from the server. You need to use additional layer in order to handle `async` behavior in redux.

For example with `redux-thunk`, you can make it work like this:

```js
import { INDEX_PRESCRIPTION } from '../constant.js';
    
function fetch_prescription(){
  const base_url= "http://192.168.1.22:3000/api/v1/";
  const fetch_url = `${base_url}/prescriptions`;
  let datas = [];
  return fetch(fetch_url, {
    method: "GET"
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => data['prescriptions']);
}
    
export const indexPrescription = (dispatch) => {
  fetch_prescription()
     .then(details => {
          const action = {
              type: INDEX_PRESCRIPTION,
              details
           }
           
           dispatch(action);
  }
}
```

Comment: I had a look at redux-thunk. And implemented your code too. Error stated as "dispatch is not a function"

Comment: You need to call it in `mapDispatchToProps` part of `connect` statement

Answer (score 0):

The part you are missing here is that the function `fetch_prescription()` is asynchronous. So the data may not be available when you are accessing the data.

You are returning the `datas` before resolving the asnyc function `return datas`

You may use it as

```
    import { INDEX_PRESCRIPTION } from '../constant.js';

    function fetch_prescription(){
      const base_url= "http://192.168.1.22:3000/api/v1/";
      const fetch_url = `${base_url}/prescriptions`;
      let datas = [];
      return fetch(fetch_url, {
        method: "GET"
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {

        datas.push(data['prescriptions'])
        return datas
      })
    }

    export const indexPrescription = async () => {
      const action = {
        type: INDEX_PRESCRIPTION,
        details: await fetch_prescription()
      }
      return action;
    }

    export const getIndexPrescription = (dispatch) => {
       dispatch(indexPrescription());
    }
```

And dispatch the above action where ever you want.

Call getIndexPrescription() in componentWillMount

Comment: on using dispatch under componentWillMount() in my component, error stated as "dispatch is not defined". Do I need to import dispatch from any function?

Comment: Still , error states that dispatch is not a function. And I have made a search for that problem also, but still cant able to figure it out.

Comment: @Thananjaya have you installed redux and redux-thuink?

Comment: npm install --save redux-thunk redux

Comment: Yes , I did installed both along with applyMiddleware from 'redux'

Comment: @Thananjaya Have you connected the component to correctly? Please add the component too, so that it will be easy to debug

Comment: Yea I have added my component in reference with your solution Sir.

Comment: @Thananjaya Cool. add the applymiddelware part

Comment: Yup, I have added src/index.js file.

Comment: @Thananjaya as per your code, you can use this.props.indexPrescription() instead of this.props.getIndexPrescription(); It doesn't make any difference

Comment: My component and src/index.js file will be in accordance with your Solution Sir.

Comment: I have changed my action in accordance with your solution Sir.

Comment: Code seems to be correct. Once remove node modules and reinstall

Answer (score 0):

Find the code below to add `redux-thunk` to your application.

```
...
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
...

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);

<Provider store={store}>
...
</Provider>
```